# after adding second string object into array first object got changed

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

after adding second string object into array first object got changed

```
[m_cObjImageNameArrayPtr addObject:m_cObjParsedStringPtr];
```

But in above statement i am calling one method and adding `m_cObjParsedStringPtr` to array, one at a time. After adding second element, first element and second element contains same value, after adding 3rd element - 1st, 2nd, 3rd are showing same values but actually they are different.

Comment: That is some horrible naming scheme you have going on there you might want to look at [Coding Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) it will certainly make your code easier to read.

Comment: How are you inspecting the array to give you these results?

Comment: is it possible you added the **same** instance twice to your array? a little bit more code would be needed to find out what is really happening. and if you can upload the output of the `NSLog(@"%@", m_cObjImageNameArrayPtr);` it would be really helpful.

Comment: in the debugger i am inspecting the all variable values.while adding string to array its old value is replcaed with new value,but count will not reduce.

Comment: m_cObjParsedStringPtr       = (NSMutableString *)nil;
        m_cObjParsedStringPtr       = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; In the called method I am appending new string value.
 [m_cObjParsedStringPtr setString:@""];  [m_cObjParsedStringPtr appendString:pObjStringPtr];
 [m_cObjImageNameArrayPtr addObject:m_cObjParsedStringPtr];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suspecting your `m_cObjParsedStringPtr` pointer points to same object every time ... put some more code

Comment: m_cObjParsedStringPtr = (NSMutableString *)nil; m_cObjParsedStringPtr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];           In the called method I am appending new string value. [m_cObjParsedStringPtr setString:@""];          [m_cObjParsedStringPtr appendString:pObjStringPtr]; [m_cObjImageNameArrayPtr addObject:m_cObjParsedStringPtr];

Comment: yes correct my m_cObjParsedStringPtr pointing to same object.How to fix this issue?

Comment: Ok.I fixed This issue by this code..                                                         NSString *lObjImageNamePtr= [m_cObjParsedStringPtr copy];
[m_cObjImageNameArrayPtr addObject:lObjImageNamePtr];                                         Thanks everybody for your reply